# Push using Parse SDK for IOS not deliver in Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using parse SDK to send push notification to friend.
NOTE: I have tested the push notification certificate manually using simple REST API,its works there.

Using below code:
 I have in installation table, channels is Array type where i have match the key :
its shows delever in parse table,but my device don't get any type of notification (check screenshot attached)

```
 PFQuery * pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[pushQuery whereKey:@"channels" containedIn:array];
NSString * alert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You have a new message from %@!", [PFUser currentUser].username]; 
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          alert, @"alert",
                          @"default", @"sound",
                          @"Increment", @"badge",
                          nil]; [PFPush sendPushDataToQueryInBackground:pushQuery withData:data block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

        }
        else {
        } }];
```

My delegate setting :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Uncomment and fill in with your Parse credentials:
    [Parse setApplicationId:@“MY APP ID
                  clientKey:@“MY CLIENT KEY”];

   // Override point for customization after application launch.
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

}



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];
    currentInstallation.channels = @[@“channel”];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];


   }


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    if (error.code == 3010) {
        //NSLog(@"Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.");
    } else {
        // show some alert or otherwise handle the failure to register.
        //NSLog(@"application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error);
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];


}

//NOTE: after login i change the channels value in installation table by 

   PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
       // [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:newDeviceToken];

        NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"channel%@",[PFUser currentUser]];
        NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:string, nil];
        currentInstallation.channels =array;
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE : using new Parse SDK for IOS 8, my problem resolved**

Answer (score 1):

If your device runs iOS 8, note that `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` is not supported anymore.

You need to use `registerUserNotificationSettings`. Here is an example code that should work both on iOS 7 (and under) and iOS 8:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {

    // Checks for iOS 8
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)) {

           [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

           [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

    } else {

          [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
                     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    }

    // The rest of your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method should be here

    return YES;
}
```

---

**Edit :** I just saw that you said it worked with the REST API, so this would not be causing your issue. It's a good thing to update your code to this though, as you may encounter issues with iOS 8 devices.

---

**Edit 2:**

The issue might come from your Parse project configuration. You need to manually enable "Client push notifications". By default, Parse disables it, which prevents the Parse SDKs to send push notifications.

Go to Parse.com, to the Settings of your app, in the Push section, and set "Client push enabled?" to "Yes".

Comment: thanks for quick answer but i already enable it,check images attached showing push deliver from parse sdk
Can i provide you Push Key so you can check in a sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

have you checked sample in given in parse.com .just add your application  [Parse

```
setApplicationId:@“MY APP ID
                  clientKey:@“MY CLIENT KEY”];
```

then run and check its working , if not working means you have done some mistake in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // ****************************************************************************

  [Parse setApplicationId:@"NlQEPXWSQgueodgfbuogbSQdF0MOzMPdvyBSvvH5sCbF2rpAW8JK" clientKey:@"qJTAqgFHck1a2TfjskfjvjfvkhhGsqycfhWgQhmnPWcNKAgGt1p"];
    // ****************************************************************************

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];

    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

and check in your code . you are getting   deviceToken correctly.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

        NSLog(@"device token===%@",deviceToken);


        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
        currentInstallation.channels = @[@"global"];
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
    }![appkey][1]
```

[image: p12]

[image]

Comment: Thanks sport,up vote for help,problem resolved by using IOS 8 SDK for parse.